# Extract Data if

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I am new to SQL and had training to enable me to use SSRS in March but we also have an oracle DB.

I need to extract phone numbers which can be held in columns called home phone, work phone or mobile phone but I want to only extract if the number starts 07 but also limit to 11 digits. The issue here is the number could be in all or any 3 of the columns.

If the number starts with anything other than 07 or if the data has text, I want to replace this with a blank.

I have looked at using

'''Select home phone,
Work phone,
Mobile no

From DB
Where home phone like '07'%
And work phone like '07'%
And mobile no like '07'%'''

But this massively reduces the data set as expected.

I have looked at replace and regexp-replace but can't quite get my head around this bit at the minute. Any help much appreciated, I think want to export all of the data just have a blank if it's not an 11 digit mobile number.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve]. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put OR instead of AND in your query. Since you mentioned you want to export data only so I think the query is to format the phone number as below:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(HOME_PHONE, 1, 2) = '07' --START WITH '07'
        AND LENGTH(HOME_PHONE) = 11      --11 DIGITS
        AND LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('HOME_PHONE', ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL --CONTAIN ONLY NUMBER
      THEN HOME_PHONE
    ELSE '' --RETURN BLANK IF CONDITION NOT MATCHED
  END AS HOME_PHONE
FROM DATA_TBL
```

You can apply the same to select WORK_PHONE and MOBILE_PHONE.

If this is not what you are looking for, please give sample data and desired output so it would be easier for me to replicate.

Comment: Thanks Hana, that's worked for me on all 3 extracts.